# Splitting varchar column into tokens (words) by multiple separator and get them as record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query working for me till now.

```
    with tmp(product_id , Token, product_name) as (
    select product_id,  cast ( LEFT(product_name, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' ')-1) as varchar(100)),
        STUFF(product_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' '), '')
    from Products 
    union all
    select product_id, cast (LEFT(product_name, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' ')-1) as varchar(100)),
        STUFF(product_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' '), '')
    from tmp
    where product_name > ''
    )

    select product_id, Token from tmp
```

This split the product name by space and provide me as records.

But now I need to split product name not only by space but by space, hyphen and comma. I am unable to figure out how to achieve this.

Any kind of help is always appreciated.

**Edit - Example**

if product table contains following

```
product_id, product_name
1, JVC-600.BLACK
2, M cb-588
```

Then I need

```
product_id, token
1, JVC
1, 600
1, BLACK
2, M
2, cb
2, 588
```

as result.

Comment: Can you post some sample data and required output

Comment: @parveen Added some example of how I need it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a query that works for spaces, a very easy modification is to make the other characters spaces as well, e.g.

```
with Prod2 as (
  select *, product_name2 = replace(replace(product_name,'.',' '),'-',' ')
  from products
)
,tmp(product_id , Token, product_name) as (
select product_id,  cast ( LEFT(product_name2, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name2+' ')-1) as varchar(100)),
    STUFF(product_name2, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name2+' '), '')
from Prod2 
union all
select product_id, cast (LEFT(product_name, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' ')-1) as varchar(100)),
    STUFF(product_name, 1, CHARINDEX(' ',product_name+' '), '')
from tmp
where product_name > ''
)

select product_id, Token from tmp
```

Comment: @ thank you very much sir but I think in the Anchor query of tmp CTE it should be "from Prod2" instead of "from products".

Comment: Absolutely right Ankit. Well spotted - does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Tune the code by using a while loop to pass the values for @var column dynamically and here dee_split  is a user defined function  , Before running this query execute the function dee_split , what you need to do is convert all special characters into single using replace function then pass it to the split function

```
        DROP TABLE #temp;
        Create table #temp
        (
        product_id varchar(10),
        product_name varchar(100)
        )

        Insert into #temp
        values  
        ('1','JVC-600.BLACK'),
        ('2','M cb-588') 

     Select * from #temp

      DECLARE @var VARCHAR(100)
SET @var='JVC-600.BLACK'

Select   @var=Replace(Replace(Replace (@var,'-','|'),'.','|'),' ','|')

    Select * from dee_split (@var,'|',null)
```

FUnction dee_split run this before running the above query

```
     CREATE FUNCTION dee_split 
    ( 
     @str varchar(max),
     @spliter char(1),
     @colspliter char(1) = null
    )
    RETURNS @tname TABLE(item VARCHAR(1000),item1 VARCHAR(1000))
    AS
    BEGIN
     DECLARE @string XML
     IF LEN(@str)=0
     BEGIN
      INSERT INTO @tname VALUES(null,null)
      RETURN
     END
     if @colspliter is null
     begin
     IF CHARINDEX(@spliter,@str,0) <> 0
     BEGIN
      SELECT @string= CONVERT(XML,'<root1><node>'+REPLACE(@str,@spliter,'</node><node>')+'</node></root1>')

      INSERT INTO @tname(item)
      SELECT  [Value]=T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
       FROM @string.nodes('/root1/node') T(c)
     END
     end
     ELSE
     BEGIN 
      IF @str IS NOT NULL
      BEGIN 
       IF  @colspliter IS NOT NULL
       SELECT @string= CONVERT(XML,'<root1><r1><node>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@str,@colspliter,'</node><node1>'),@spliter,'</node1></r1><r1><node>')+'</node1></r1></root1>')
       INSERT INTO @tname 
       SELECT col.value('data(node[1])','varchar(16)') item,
       col.value('data(node1[1])','varchar(9)') item1
       FROM @string.nodes('root1/r1') AS tbl(col)
      END
     END
    RETURN
    END
```